# How to convert typing in English to Malayalam?

Tags: language-support, translation

I know malayalam language. But I don't have typing speed in malayalam. How can one type malayalam in English? E.g.: if I Type "MALAYALAM" then it should appear as malayalam in malayalam language. How is it possible?

Comment: its not possible in Ubuntu default, Use it in Google translator or in Babylon translation or use gmail ...

Comment: you can use swanalekha in ibus

Answer (score 1):

You can use Malayalam phonetics applications or websites. There are so many Manglish websites and applications are available in online

for example [vanmaram](http://www.vanmaram.com/) online English Malayalam dictionary

Answer (score 1):

Please try this
http://www.google.com/intl/ml/inputtools/try/

if you type "MALAYALAM", it will display as "മലയാളം".